# texstudio: print PDF instead of source?

Tags: texstudio, printing

Pardon this as an application question, I'll go elsewhere if I need to, but I'm not sure where else to ask. I am using textstudio 2.8.4 in linux. I have my document ready to print. When I goto File> print, the source is what is printed. I was hoping that the pdf would print. So I am opening a separate program to then print the output.

is there a way to print the output pdf from texstudio directly?

Comment: Printing the PDF is not offered in TS (at least it wasn't a few years ago). They usually recommend printing via a dedicated PDF previewer. (This makes it a lot easier to port TS between different systems)

Comment: Ok Then. So, Atleast Im doing everything right. I actualy have an idea for a DE specific script / macro I can write to get the preview to print.

Comment: Isn't there a button to open the pdf in Adobe Reader (or similar external viewer)?